# Ubuntu as a server?

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, webserver, ip

I have installed latest Ubuntu (12.04) on my pc, and when I do `ifconfig` it shows this IP: `192.168.1.22`.

I dont want to use internal ip, I want to use it as a server.

However when I visit [www.whatismyip.com](http://www.whatismyip.com) website it is actually showing my IP `27.82.XXX.XXX`

How can I get this IP on my pc, So that I can use my pc as a server.

Comment: Read about [port forwarding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) and configure your router. Probably you don't have static IP so you should use [dynamic DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS)

Comment: You can get that ip only if it's yours (have a static ip from the provider). Just because you see 27.... does not mean you can have it. 192... is the ip of you pc in the local network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 27.82.XXX.XXX IP is actually the global IP of your internet router, not your PC/server.  If you want to be able to access your server using that IP, you will need to **forward** the proper ports from your router to the local IP of your server (192.168.1.22).  For example, if you want to use it as a web server, you will probably need to forward ports 80 (HTTP) and/or 443 (HTTPS).  Or if you need SSH access, forward port 22.  [Here](http://www.howtogeek.com/66214/how-to-forward-ports-on-your-router/) is a good guide that explains how to do it.

Also, unless you have a static IP from your internet provider, don't expect that your global IP will stay the same.  That's where [dynamic DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) comes in.  It allows you to assign a hostname that will always point to your server even when the IP changes.  I personally prefer [dnsdynamic.org](http://dnsdynamic.org/) because it's simple, free, and unlimited.

Comment: i am having static ip then what to do ?

Comment: thanks that is really helpful information. @jStiffs thanks :)